# Cast type given a type name

Tags: json, postgresql

I have this json structure where i also store a PostgreSQL type name

```
{  
   "temperature":{  
      "value":"(-75,-70]",
      "type":"int4range"
   }
}
```

i can get the value such as

```
SELECT '{"temperature":{"value":"(-75,-70]","type":"int4range"}}'::jsonb #> ARRAY['temperature','value']
```

now the value type is text and i know that i can only store simple types in json but how can i convert the value to `int4range` dynamically using the type name i have?

Comment: I think that dynamic casts are impossible in Postgres. You can of course do this inside a plpgsql function but you won't be able to properly return the result.

Comment: @klin thank you, that was helpful just wanted to make sure its not straight forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @Bread said you can't dynamically cast data.

However you could do something like:

```
WITH jsonb as (
    SELECT '{"temperature":{"value":"[-75,-70]","type":"int4range"}}'::json
), fromjsonb as (
    SELECT json->'temperature'->'value' as element,
           json->'temperature'->'type' as type
    FROM jsonb
), trim as (
    SELECT trim(both '"' from element::text) as element,
           trim(both '"' from type::text) as type
    FROM fromjsonb
)
SELECT CASE WHEN type = 'int4range' THEN element::int4range
            -- ELSE element::text
            END
FROM trim;

   case    
-----------
 [-75,-69)
(1 row)
```

In my example it selects the data and that can't work because PostgreSQL will not let you select a first row as `int4range` then the following one as another type.

But you can use this same logic to insert data in another table (which I assume is your goal) and that will work.